# Magento2: Hide custom module field if the Require Emails Confirmation is active

Tags: magento2

I need to hide the custom module field if the "Require Emails Confirmation" option is active.

Here is the screenshot for more detail

[image]

[image]

Here is my  code:

```
<section id="abc_mkt" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="22" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
         <class>abc_settings</class>
         <label>Settings</label>
         <tab>mkt</tab>
         <resource>Abc_Mkt::abc_mkt</resource>

         <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Customer Sync </label>
            <field id="mkt_lead_integration" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
               <!-- add a new field with id scope -->
               <label>Enable Customer Sync on Signup</label>
               <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                <depends>
                    <field id="customer/create_account/confirm">1</field>
                </depends>
            </field>

         </group>

      </section>
```

Please suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: You cannot use depends if fields are belongs to different tabs.

Comment: What i can do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use depends field in your **system.xml** then it will work only for same section and tab but as you want to use different section and tab for dependency you can try the following steps also magento uses display none and block if you use depends field. So you approach will be:

**Step 1:** create one block class to your module into following path:

> app/code/Abc/Mkt/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config.php

with below contents:

```
<?php
namespace Abc\Mkt\Block\Adminhtml\System;

class Config extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data = []
        ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent :: __construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function isAccountConfirm()
    {
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('customer/create_account/confirm', $storeScope);
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Create layout file under below location:

> app/code/Abc/Mkt/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="Abc\Mkt\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config" name="hide_config" template="Abc_Mkt::system/config.phtml" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**Step 3:** Create template file under below location:

> app/code/Abc/Mkt/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config.phtml

with below contents:

```
<?php if($block->isAccountConfirm()): ?>
  <style type="text/css">
    #row_your_module_general_mkt_lead_integration {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now in Step 3 your need to mention your row id which you need to hide.

**Update for auto set config value when customer/account/confirm is active:**

**Step 1:** Create **events.xml** under:

> app/code/Abc/Mkt/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

with below contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="my_module_predispatch" instance="Abc\Mkt\Observer\ConfigUpdate" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Step 2:** Create **ConfigUpdate.php** under:

> app/code/Abc/Mkt/Observer/ConfigUpdate.php

with below contents:

```
<?php
namespace Abc\Mkt\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface;

class ConfigUpdate implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $scopeConfig;

    protected $configWriter;

    protected $websiteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        WriterInterface $configWriter,
        \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository $websiteRepository
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->configWriter = $configWriter;
        $this->websiteRepository = $websiteRepository;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        $actionFullName = ($request->getFullActionName());
        if ($actionFullName == 'adminhtml_system_config_edit') {
            if ($this->isAccountConfirm()) {
                $this->configWriter->save('section_name/general/mkt_lead_integration', 0, $scope = \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public function isAccountConfirm()
    {
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('customer/create_account/confirm', $storeScope);
    }
}
```

Thats it!

Comment: Thanks, I will check and update you once done

Comment: You are Great! it works for me.

Comment: Welcome! Happy Coding!

Comment: @sukumat At the same need to update the drop-down field. I have a yes and no values field. Need to save No in drop down field

Comment: When it will be No?

Comment: when we are hiding the field same fieldneed to save no

Comment: I am doing but not working

Comment: What you have done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102788/discussion-between-shiwani-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: please check in chat

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below for hiding and displaying the fields inside your field section in system.xml file.

```
<section id="abc_mkt" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="22" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
     <class>abc_settings</class>
     <label>Settings</label>
     <tab>customer</tab>
     <resource>Abc_Mkt::abc_mkt</resource>
     <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Customer Sync </label>
        <field id="mkt_lead_integration" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
           <!-- add a new field with id scope -->
           <label>Enable Customer Sync on Signup</label>
           <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            <depends>
                    <field id="confirm">1</field>
            </depends>
        </field>
     </group>
  </section>
```

Comment: I have checked with this but its not working

Comment: Can you add your snippet in your question so we can try to clear in right way.

Comment: Updated comment with code

Comment: I had updated my answer please try it.

Comment: This is also not working

Comment: Can you share the file path of the file which you are using.

Comment: app\code\Abc\Mkt\etc\adminhtml\system.xml

Comment: I updated the code try that

Comment: What you have updated?

Comment: I changed the tab name.

Comment: It will not affect any result with tab name change

Comment: I tried here and working fine as expected.

Comment: Can you please it's not working at my end?